# iTunes doesn't sync all titles from a Playlist

Tags: itunes, data-synchronization, ios, ipod-touch

I'm facing some issues synchronizing an iTunes playlist with my iPod Touch, 3G, iOS 5.1.1. My iTunes version is 10.6.3.25.

My playlist contains 180 mp3-podcasts. If I want to synchronize it with my iPod, it happens that only 153 podcasts got transferred: 27 podcasts are missing and I don't know why.

- My iPod is not full. The playlist is 2,85 GB big and my iPod has 19GB free memory.
- there shouldn't be a problem with the file format. There's no problem playing them in iTunes.
- all titles are linked properly (to a data-path on my harddrive)
- Actually all titles should be synchronized, because I put checkmarks on each of the titles.
- I deleted and recreated the playlist in iTunes already several times.

Could it be that a Playlist on iPods has just a certain capacy for titles/hours/GB? Or what could be the problem? Any idea?

Comment: Create a playlist with the missing podcasts and try to sync. If they do, there is a problem with the playlist, if not there is a problem with the podcasts.

Comment: thanks for your suggestion. I'll try it out and report my result later. I realized that all playlists with podcasts are incomplete.

Comment: okay. If I put all the missing podcasts in a new playlist, it happens that this playlist can't be synchronized, because it simply doesn't appear in the list. So there must be an issue with the podcasts... I just don't know what's the matter. Thanks for helping me figuring it out.

Comment: You’re welcome. Perhaps the problematic podcasts were downloaded through a different Apple ID and your iPod isn’t authorised to play them.